# profiling an ASP.Net web application taking loads of memory (>1.2GB) over time

Tags: asp.net, caching, memory-management, memory-leaks, httpruntime.cache

I have a web application which on first page load takes approximately 200MB of memory.  In production, by a relatively short time (< 24hours), it grows up to sometimes 1.2GB of usage.  Is there any way one can check what is taking so much memory, especially in production and not in development environment, where I cannot replicate exactly the scenario?

Also, the website is using extensively output caching and the HttpRuntime caching.  Is there any way to know how much memory is being consumed?  Is it possible to limit the HttpRuntime cache to a maximum amount of memory?

I'm relatively new to memory profiling - any help / guidelines would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are products and tools that can help you with this, some are free and some are not, take a look at these:

- [SciTech .NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/productioncode.aspx) - not free
- [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/) - not free
- [RedGate ANTS Performance Profiler 8](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) - not free
- [CLRProfiler](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14727) - free

Comment: Anyone which you personally recommend, even if not the free version?

Comment: @KarlCassar - I have use CLRProfiler since the .NET 1.1 days so I use that out of habit, but I normally profile development or a staging environment. If I had to pick one of the pay ones, then I would go with the JetBrains dotTrace, as I am a happy user of ReSharper and have not heard too many bad things about JetBrains' products. If you feel this answer helped you, then feel free to accept and/or up-vote the answer. Good luck to you. :-)